# Update/Change SSRS DataSource(Not Shared) Programmatically

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have asp.net application and for reporting purpose we are using SSRS report.

SSRS report project, I am using DataSource1 for all reports. (Consider Database Name : DB1)

How do I change the ConnectionString property of DataSource1 (Here I want to change DB1 to DB2) programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

As the data source are not shared, they are embedded in the reports rdl files which essentially are XML files. Probably the easiest way is amend these xml directly.
Depending on the complexity of the reports, changing the datasource could be done as a simple string replacement, but a more robust solution would be a contextual change
using an xml library for example in powershell:

```
$Rdl = [xml] (gc -path "c:....path to report xx.rdl ...")
$Rdl.Report.DataSources.DataSource |
% {if ($_.GetAttribute("Name") -eq "DataSource1") {
    NewDS = $._ConnectionProperties.ConnectString.Replace("DB1","DB2")
    $._ConnectionProperties.ConnectString=$NewDS}
    }
$Rdl.Save("c:....path to modified rdl ...")
```

this example works for ssrs-2012 not sure if the xpath to datasources are the same in other versions.